# Setting values for dbVisualizer Pro directly in the SQL code

Tags: dbvisualizer

In dbVisualizer I can define variables for which I need to provide values once I run the code, in the figure it was e.g. `${Table}`. Is it possible to set the values for these variable directly in the SQL?

[image: dbvisualizer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a default value for a variable: `${Table||myDefaultTable}`. Read more about [variables](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG/Using+DbVisualizer+Variables) in DbVisualizer.